# Linker command failed with exit code 1......ios project error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-analytics, linker

I am working with an XCode project which was fine yesterday but today without any change in code I am getting following compile error.
Any suggestion? How can i fix it?

```
Ld DerivedData/OEiPhone/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project\ Sounds.app/Project\ Sounds normal i386
cd "/Users/admin/Desktop/App 2"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L/Users/admin/Desktop/App\ 2/DerivedData/OEiPhone/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/admin/Desktop/App\ 2/Classes/ListControl/OELib -L/Users/admin/Desktop/App\ 2/../../../iPad/API\'s/Google\ Analytics\ SDK/Library -L/Users/admin/Desktop/App\ 2/Classes/Analytic -LLibrary -F/Users/admin/Desktop/App\ 2/DerivedData/OEiPhone/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/admin/Desktop/App\ 2/DerivedData/OEiPhone/Build/Intermediates/OEiPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project\ Sounds.build/Objects-normal/i386/Project\ Sounds.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -licucore -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework NewsstandKit -lsqlite3.0 -lz.1.2.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -lGoogleAnalytics_NoThumb -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework CoreText -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework StoreKit -lxml2 -lGoogleAnalytics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/admin/Desktop/App\ 2/DerivedData/OEiPhone/Build/Intermediates/OEiPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project\ Sounds.build/Objects-normal/i386/Project\ Sounds_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/admin/Desktop/App\ 2/DerivedData/OEiPhone/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project\ Sounds.app/Project\ Sounds


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Desktop/App 2/Classes/ListControl/OELib'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Desktop/App 2/../../../iPad/API's/Google Analytics SDK/Library'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Desktop/App 2/Classes/Analytic'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LLibrary'

ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalytics_NoThumb
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Maybe you lack the configuration in Linker? Read the manual carefully. As I use googleMaps API, they request a linker "-Objective C"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Make sure to remove the library in your 
Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries 
if you removed it or add it if it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

This path

/Users/admin/Desktop/App 2/../../../iPad/API's/Google Analytics SDK/Library

Is pointing at a Library on your desktop. Is that library still there, or did you move/delete it?